# Laravel - returning only certain columns within a has function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, pivot-table

Currently, the function below works correctly, however, the `->has('alerts')` returns the entire array of `alerts` including all relationship data. I want to return only certain columns from that relationship.

```
public function getMatches()
        {
            $matches = Criteria::select('id')
            ->has('alerts')
            ->with(['alerts.location' => function($w){
                $w->select('id');
            }])
            ->with('alerts.user.companies')
            ->where('user_id', Auth::id())
            ->get();

            return Response::json(array(
                'matches' => $matches,
                'status' => '200'
                )
            );

        }
```

The columns that I'd like to return can be accessed within blade format **(note the pivot that is also used)**:

```
@foreach($matches as $match)
    @foreach($match->alerts as $alert)  
        {{$alert->pivot->criteria_id}}
        {{$alert->pivot->alert_id}}
        {{$alert->price_value}}
        {{$alert->location->type}}
        {{$alert->category}}
        {{$alert->description}}
        {{$alert->category}}
        {{$alert->user->companies->first()->logo->url('thumb')}}
        {{$alert->pivot->viewed}} 
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

I have tried the following:

```
public function getMatches()
    {
        $matches = Criteria::select('id')
        ->has(['alerts' => function ($q){
            $q->select('id', 'pivot.criteria_id');
        }])
        ->with(['alerts.location' => function($w){
            $w->select('id');
        }])
        ->with('alerts.user.companies')
        ->where('user_id', Auth::id())
        ->get();

    }
```

But I'm presented with the following error:

```
strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

The error occurs when the following function is added to the `has()` function:

```
->has(['alerts' => function ($q){
    $q->select('id', 'pivot.criteria_id');
}])
```

Any help as to how I can select said fields from the 'alerts' table and the according relationships I'd be highly appreciative.

Comment: Is `strpos()` being called somewhere within Laravel's `->has()` function? Or did you call it somewhere? I only ask because I don't see you calling it anywhere.

Comment: As soon as I add the `function` into the `has()`, the error happens, so I'm pretty confident this is where the error is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to use `has` or `whereHas` for that. The `has` functions are only to filter the result based on a relation. To only select certain columns use `with()`

```
$matches = Criteria::select('id')
    ->has('alerts')
    ->with(['alerts' => function($q){
        $q->select('id', 'pivot.criteria_id');
    }, 'alerts.location' => function($w){
        $w->select('id');
    }])
    ->with('alerts.user.companies')
    ->where('user_id', Auth::id())
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have something like this:

```
->has(['alerts' => function ($q){
    //...
}])
```

It should be like this:

```
->whereHas('alerts', function ($q){
    //...
})
```